# Problem with clipboard when using extended ASCII characters (chars > 127) on Japanese versions of Windows

Tags: fonts, clipboard, cjk

After more research and writing a couple of demo apps in both C++ and C#, I am revising this question to better target the issue that I have been seeing.

**Problem statement:** I have a (Visual Studio) MFC Unicode app that is used by some people in Japan. One of the app's functions outputs an enhanced metafile to the clipboard for pasting into other applications. The MFC app is an OLE server app and uses COleServerItem::CopyToClipboard to add the metafile to the clipboard. Some of the text in the metafile use glyphs with character codes > 127. On a Japanese version of Windows (with a en-US language pack installed), those glyphs do not render properly when pasted into another application. Instead of the expected symbols, they are rendered as some latin chars in some other font. Doesn't make any difference what font is used.

The following is what a demonstration MFC app draws to the screen using special characters from the Symbol font:
[image]
When copying and pasting the above enhanced metafile into WordPad on a Japanese version of windows, the result is:
[image]
If I change the strings that use the glyphs from CString(wchar_t) to CStringA (char), and use TextOutA instead of the Unicode verison, then the glyphs do render properly!

An additional workaround, instead of using COleServerItem::CopyToClipboard, is to "manually" put data on the clipboard using standard C++ clipboard functions like OpenClipboard, EmptyClipboard, SetClipboardData, CloseClipboard. This also fixes the problem without having to change the strings in the metafile to ANSI. So one might think that the problem is in COleServerItem::CopyToClipboard.
However, there is a related problem that doesn't involve the clipboard. The app uses a legacy MSFlexGrid OCX. The com object uses OLE which is Unicode, but on a Japanes Windows system, when the grids are displayed on screen, the special glyphs (extended ascii char codes > 127) also render improperly.
Note that if one just copies and pastes plain text in whatever font, then there isn't a problem.

I have created a Git repository (this one) with a Visual Studio MFC solution that demonstrates the problem at https://github.com/brewerpm/JapaneseWinClipboardUnicodeProblem.git.
Steps to reproducing the problem using the demo app:

1. Build the solution.
2. Copy the .exe to a Japanese verison of Windows.
3. Run the program to display the output.
4. Select the method to use to create the metafile:

   a. Use CClipboardDemoSrvrItem::CopyToClipboard with Unicode strings.

   b. Use CClipboardDemoSrvrItem::CopyToClipboard with ANSI strings.

   c. Use C++ clipboard functions OpenClipboard, EmptyClipboard, SetClipboardData, CloseClipboard with Unicode strings.
5. Use Edit->Copy or ctrl-c to copy the output to the clipboard as an enhanced metafile.
6. Paste into WordPad (or Word if installed) and verify that the "extended" characters from the Symbol font are rendered improperly in some other (fallback) font when using method (a) but are rendered properly when using method (b) or (c).

Other things I have tried:

- Adding a CF_LOCALE record to the clipboard that specifies "en-US" using the following code:
- Setting the codepage to Western 1252.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more info? It would help to see an example of how you are selecting the font, a string you are drawing and how you are drawing it, and the visual result you see from that drawing operation or from the copy/paste scenario.

Comment: Just because I'm curious: why are you using GDI+ at all, instead of DirectDraw? (Given that GDI+ basically died with Windows 7, it's curious to see someone use it for Windows 10)

Comment: Hi, Mike. I suppose you're referring to Direct2D/DirectWrite (DirectDraw was deprecated a long time ago I believe).Certainly Direct2D/DirectWrite would be the way to go now, but this app, while having lots of new, more modern code, is basically a legacy MFC app. While GDI+ has been around a long time, it is still an integral part of the Windows OS, and I doubt that is the source of the problem here. There are probably tens of thousands of apps out that still use GDI+ and transitioning Direct2D takes some work that is lower down on my list of things to do ;)

Comment: Yes, Peter, I will post more information soon and thanks for asking.

Comment: Peter - I have revised the description of the problem, added more pertinent information and provided an demo app on GitHub that illustrates the issue.